# when trying to install windows 7 on my computer it inly gets to 30 % then gets the blue screen

Tags: windows, boot, display

I have tried both vista and windows 7. I have gotten a new hard drive and it does the same thing. Not sure where to go from here to get windows loaded.

Comment: Try swapping out the RAM, or if you have more than one stick, remove and swap them around.

Comment: What Are your computers specs? Processor, RAM, motherboard, graphics...

Answer (score 0):

Did the PC have vista/7 on it before?  If not, is it compatible?
Do you meet the minimum requirements for the OS?

I see issues related to energy management, make sure turn off hard drive is disabled.  Since you don't have a OS installed check the bios settings.  You can always turn it on later.

Answer (score 0):

Might be problem with RAM as commented bu Rudolph.

But, I cannot really say much without knowing why the blue screen occurs.
Read the STOP error message.
Its is in CAPITAL letters and usually in first few lines on the text.

Example:

```
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
```

and corresponding error code is:

```
STOP 0×00000050
```

also note the STOP error code and refer [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/tp/stop_error_list.htm) page to get exact error.

Also go through [this](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t3.html) page which lists most common causes of blue screen and associated messages/codes.